Show most recent description from Activity on Account
We have a requirement to show the most recent description from the associated  Tasks to the Account Page , Lightening Record Page Component  ( eg: select Description from Task where Description != null order by CreatedDate LIMIT 1 ) But Salesforce does not allow 'Description' to be filtered. Looking for some ideas to implement this preferably without creating any additional fields/trigger. We already have 20+ Millions  Accounts .

Welcome to SFSE.  Please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour].  Since you can't use long textarea in formulas or in SOQL query criteria, you have no choice but to use a custom field with Apex trigger
